# WebSocket Unexpected response code: 400, RFC 6455 protocol said response like HTML?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, websocket

When I send an header through WebSocket, Google Chrome, Safari response with Unexpected response.

This is the header I send back when handshake failed:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

This is the error I get back

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Unexpected response code: 404

In RFC 6455 protocol I read a browser have to handle it like normal HTML error.
But the browsers send me back an "Unexpected response code: 4040".

Do I need to send back more headers, or have I to send a WebSocket closing frame (what is not confirm the RFC 6455 protocol).

I send the header in UTF-8.